# How to push elements in embedded schema in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

There is some confusion that I have. Below is my `Customer` schema:

```js
[
{
    _id: 'xxx',
    name: 'AAAA',
    email: 'adfasd',
    phone_number: '',
    password: 'abc123',
    orders: [
        {
            _id: 'xxx',
            restaurant_id: 'abc',
            restaurant_name: 'abc',
            location: [77.623022, 12.936933],
            address_1: ' ',
            address_2: ' ',
            img_url: '',
            Items: [
                {
                    _id: 'xxx', 
                    price: 250, 
                    name: 'Cheese Burger', 
                    quantity: 3, 
                    veg: false
                },
                {
                    _id: 'xxx',
                    price: 160,
                    name: 'Spring rolls',
                    quantity: 4,
                    veg: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

So initially the order is `[ ]`. I am confused about how to push new orders. Like when I tried to enter new orders using mongoose, it's just replacing the older ones instead of pushing the new orders

```js
router.patch('/order/:cust_id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.cust_id;

    // Getting new order details
    const orders = {
        restaurant_id: req.body.restaurant_id,
        restaurant_name: req.body.restaurant_name,
        location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: req.body.location},
        address_1: req.body.address_1,
        address_2: req.body.address_2,
        img_url: req.body.img_url,
        items: req.body.items
    };

    // Filering the document by customer_id
    let customerData = await Customer.find({_id: id});

    // Combining old orders with new
    const update = [...customerData[0].orders, orders];

    // Updating it
    Customer.findOneAndUpdate(id, {orders: update}, {useFindAndModify: false})
        .then(() => res.json('Orders updated Successfully'))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to insert the new element. It also avoids race conditions.

```
router.patch('/order/:cust_id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.cust_id;

    // Getting new order details
    const order = {
        restaurant_id: req.body.restaurant_id,
        restaurant_name: req.body.restaurant_name,
        location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: req.body.location},
        address_1: req.body.address_1,
        address_2: req.body.address_2,
        img_url: req.body.img_url,
        items: req.body.items
    };

    // Updating it
    Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id, 
        {$push: {orders: order}}
    )
        .then(() => res.json('Orders updated Successfully'))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```